# Confusing .constructor property in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The code below is what I test in browser.

```
function A(){}
a = new A()

a.__proto__ === a //false
a.__proto__.constructor === a.constructor //true
```

It's confusing for me why `a.__proto__` and `a` share the same `.constructor`

Comment: *"It's really confusing why the constructor property is implemented this way."* Why?

Comment: You are overestimating how much your question makes sense, in absence of an explicit question. There is nothing confusing there for me, it is quite obvious from the way prototypal inheritance works in JS. Please clarify, or the question is likely to be closed as vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a.__proto__ === a` is false because `a` is not its own prototype. They're separate objects

`a.__proto__.constructor === a.constructor` is true because the `a` object *inherits* the `constructor` property from its prototype. So you can access the property on `a` (indirectly) or on its prototype.

When you do `a = new A()`, here's a rough idea of what you have in memory (handwaving away some details), which may help:

```
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     |                                                             |
     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                          |
A−−−−+−>|  (function)   |                                          |
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                          |
        | name: "A"     |                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
        | prototype     |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−>|   (object)    | |
        | [[Prototype]] |−>Function.prototype |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
        | [[Code]]      |                     |  | constructor   |−+                
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |  | [[Prototype]] |−>Object.prototype
                                              |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                          |  
a−>|   (object)    |                          |
   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                          |
   | [[Prototype]] |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

(`[[Prototype]]` is a link to the object's prototype, the value returned by the deprecated `__proto__` and by the modern `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. Also: `Function.prototype`'s prototype is `Object.prototype`, not shown above.)

`A` is a constructor function. It has a property, `prototype`, which points to the object that will be used as the prototype of objects created via `new A`. `a` is an object created via `new A`, so its prototype (`[[Prototype]]`) is that same object. The `A.prototype` object has a property, `constructor`, that refers back to the constructor function it's associated with (in the simple, default case).

It becomes a bit more useful when you have two instances, `a1` and `a2`. Let's modify the code a bit:

```js
// Part 1
function A(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
A.prototype.method = function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
};

// Part 2
const a1 = new A("one");
const a2 = new A("two");

a1.method(); // "one"
a2.method(); // "two"
```

After Part 1 above runs, we have something like this (again, leaving out some details, and I've used `Fp` and `Op` instead of `Function.prototype` and `Object.prototype` to save space):

```
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     |                                           |
     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                        |
A−−−−+−>|  (function)   |                        |
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                        |
        | name: "A"     |      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
        | prototype     |−−−−−>|   (object)    | |
        | [[Prototype]] |−>Fp  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
        | [[Code]]      |      | constructor   |−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      | method        |−−−−−>|   (function)   |
                               | [[Prototype]] |−>Op  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      | name: "method" |
                                                      | [[Prototype]]  |−>Fp
                                                      | [[Code]]       |
                                                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

After the `const a1 = new A("one");` line, we have:

```
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     |                                              |
     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                           |
A−−−−+−>|  (function)   |                           |
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                           |
        | name: "A"     |         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
        | prototype     |−−−−−−+−>|   (object)    | |
        | [[Prototype]] |−>Fp  |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
        | [[Code]]      |      |  | constructor   |−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      |  | method        |−−−−−>|   (function)   |
                               |  | [[Prototype]] |−>Op  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                               |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      | name: "method" |
                               |                         | [[Prototype]]  |−>Fp
                               |                         | [[Code]]       |
                               |                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
a1−−>|   (object)    |         |
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
     | foo: "one"    |         |
     | [[Prototype]] |−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

After the `const a2 = new A("two");` line, we have:

```
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     |                                              |
     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                           |
A−−−−+−>|  (function)   |                           |
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                           |
        | name: "A"     |         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
        | prototype     |−−−−−−+−>|   (object)    | |
        | [[Prototype]] |−>Fp  |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
        | [[Code]]      |      |  | constructor   |−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      |  | method        |−−−−−>|   (function)   |
                               |  | [[Prototype]] |−>Op  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                               |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      | name: "method" |
                               |                         | [[Prototype]]  |−>Fp
                               |                         | [[Code]]       |
                               |                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
a1−−>|   (object)    |         |
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
     | foo: "one"    |         |
     | [[Prototype]] |−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
                               |
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
a2−−>|    (object)   |         |
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
     | foo: "two"    |         |
     | [[Prototype]] |−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

That shows how the prototype is useful for shared features. `a1` and `a2` don't need to have their own copies of `method`, they just inherit it from their prototype.

---

Side note: `__proto__` is deprecated. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf(a)` to get the prototype of `a`, rather than `a.__proto__`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It's quite helpful.

    `a instanceof A //true`

    `a.constructor === A //true`
    
    `Object.getPrototypeOf(a) instanceof Object //true`

   `Object.getPrototypeOf(a).constructor === Object //false`


I was expecting that if `some_object` is an instance of `another_object`, then `another_object` should be the constructor of `some_object`. It appears that it's not the case.

Comment: @Sean - `obj instanceof Ctor` looks to see if `Ctor.prototype` is anywhere in `obj`'s inheritance chain. So `a instanceof A` is true because `a`'s immediate prototype is `A.prototype`. `a instanceof Object` is also true, because the prototype of `a`'s prototype is `Object.prototype`. (`Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(a)) === Object.prototype`.)

Comment: @Sean - I've updated the answer to show `Object.prototype` and `Function.prototype` in the places they go, for more clarity. (Also, a couple of the lines in the final two diagrams were misplaced.) Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

`A.prototype.constructor == A` for any function `A`; `a.__proto__ == A.prototype` for any object `a` constructed by `new A`; `a.constructor` doesn't exist, so it is looked up up the prototype chain just like any other attribute, and is found at `a.__proto__.constructor`.